# Is there any media player that can playback MSS2-encoded videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, wmv

I have a video that is encoded with Microsoft's Windows Media Screen encoder (the FOURCC for the video codec is MSS2).

Is there anything on Ubuntu that will play this format?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/176900/cant-open-wmv-video-files which has an accepted answer.

Comment: @MariusGedminas: How is this a duplicate? That question refers to standard WMV files - I'm referring to MSS2-encoded files. The accepted answer on that question doesn't work either.

Comment: The question I linked to explicitly mentions "MSS2", which is why I assumed it was a duplicate.  It's possible that there's an unmentioned variable in the problem: whether you're using a 32-bit or a 64-bit version of Ubuntu.  I saw it mentioned somewhere that 32-bit builds of mplayer lack support for MSS2.

Answer (score 3):

If neither [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) nor [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can handle that then probably nothing would.

Comment: agree with Adam.