# Can't open .wmv video files

Tags: 12.04, vlc, plugins, syslinux

I installed 12.04 and installed all plug-ins related to video drive.

I installed VLC player and tried to start a `.wmv` file but I get this error:

> **No suitable decoder module:
>   VLC does not support the audio or video format "MSS2". Unfortunately there is no way for 
>   you to fix this.**

I followed links of previous .wmv related questions and also searched on Google but did not find a solution to the problem.

Please help me or suggest me any other player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted*
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried everything including installing ubuntu-restricted-extras, medibuntu w32codecs, MPlayer etc. 
Finally SMPlayer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

The Mplayer should have the codec required to play .wmv

Comment: thanks for reply .I already installed GNOME Mplayer and tried its working but cant see any video.it just audio.I want to see video file

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=39675) they suggest using vlc with `--codec dmo`