# VLC MSS2 codec missing

Tags: 12.04, multimedia, codecs

I was Playing a video in VLC but it displayed the error message

VLC does not support the audio or video format "MSS2"

How to solve this error

[image: VLC]

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/176900/cant-open-wmv-video-files which has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

VLC does not support MSS2 codec for now. It should be supported in release 2.1 as can be seen from the comments here https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/750. The latest version available for download for now is 2.0.4. So wait for version 2.1 or try some other player for example MPlayer which supports MSS2 codec.

Comment: Can u recommend any because the default ones dont work either

Comment: You can try mplayer. it supports MSS2 codec.